# How to show that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle y^2-P(x)\rangle$ is not a UFD (unique factorization domain)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, unique-factorization-domains

> I am having trouble showing that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle y^2-P(x)\rangle$, where $P\in \mathbb{C}[x]$, $\deg P\geq 2$, is not a UFD.

I actually don't really know where to begin... I've looked for any counterexamples, i.e. a term that has two factorziations, but couldn't find one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to show that it is a UFD or that it isn't?

Comment: A LaTeX tip: `<` and `>` mean "less than" and "greater than", and produce spacing correct for *that meaning only*. When you want angle brackets, you need to use `\langle` and `\rangle`. You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: Please tell us exactly(!) what you want to prove. When $P$ has no multiple roots, then your ring is regular and therefore UFD. But when $P$ is a square, then your ring is not even an integral domain.

Comment: @Martin: A regular ring is **locally** a UFD!  In dimension one the obstruction is precisely the Picard group...which will be nontrivial here if $\operatorname{deg}(P) \geq 3$.

Comment: ...and sometimes it is a UFD. Take for example $P(x)=1-x^2$. The resulting coordinate ring is isomorphic to the ring of Laurent polynomials $\Bbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]$ in one variable, and this is a UFD.

Comment: Sorry for the mistype! I meant to write not UFD... The polynomials are above $mathbb{C}$ , and the degree of P is greater than 1, so the quotient ring is not supposed to be a UFD. Keep in mind the question is regarding the quotient ring.

Comment: @Pete: Yes I know that. But when $P$ has no multiple roots (actually it suffices that $P$ is not a square), $Y^2-P(x)$ is irreducible by Eisenstein.

Comment: @Martin: my issue was that you are claiming that the ring is a UFD, which in fact it isn't if(f) $\operatorname{deg}(P) \geq 3$.  Your arguments seem to be showing that it's always an integral domain, which is certainly true.  In fact (by what you say) it's always a Dedekind domain.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Isn't a regular integral domain a UFD? And is Snir's claim correct after all?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: for an example of a non-UFD, which is a regular integral domain consider the ring of integers of the number field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ (cf. Neukirch, I.3.)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Every regular *local* ring is a UFD, by  Auslander–Buchsbaum theorem and nothing more.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: your argument is exactly the same as someone else who erased his answer a couple of minutes ago. In the factorization $y \cdot y=(x-a)(x-b) \cdots,$ $y$ (or $\overline{y}$) is *not* necessarily irreducible in the quotient ring. (Unless you prove it though!)

Comment: @Ehsan M.Kermani: you're right, that's a crucial point. (My excuse for sloppiness is that my comment was directed at Martin, not the OP. I deleted it, since it seems to increase the entropy of the discussion.)

Comment: @Snir: please change $\deg P\ge 2$ to $\deg P\ge 3$.